# Updating a Map in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Alright, i have a big issue with this.
Most of the Questions with similar issues, didn't quite help me cause they had a very different approach.

I'm trying to edit the data in a Profile. Im using a Map to access the Data.

Now when i try to set the new Map an Error appears: "Only static members can be accessed in initializers."

i show you all the code. its not everything and i changed some parts to see better what i mean. i hope you guys understand it.

```
class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
  Tabs({this.infos});

  final Map<String, dynamic> info;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _Tabs();
  }
}

class _Tabs extends State<Tabs> {
  int _currentIndex = 0; //Bottom Navigation


  final List<Widget> _children = [
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        primaryColorDark: Colors.cyan[700],
        primaryColorLight: Colors.cyan[200],
        accentColor: Colors.deepOrange[200],
      ),
      home: Suche(), //not important..
    ),
    Center(child: Text("2")), //some dummy page
    Chats(),// some other dummy page
    Profile(userInformationen: _infosTabs, updateProfile: _updateProfile), //the Profile Page plus the Error appears "Only static members can be accessed in initializers."
  ];

  void _updateProfil(Map<String, dynamic> newMap) {
    setState(() {
          _infos = newMap;
        });
  } //here i want to update the info i receive

  final Map<String, dynamic> _infos = ({
    'title': "Title",
    'name': "name",
    'points': 73,
    'about me': "texttexttexttexttext"
  });


class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  Profile({this.userInformationen, this.updateProfile});

  final Map<String, dynamic> userInformationen;

  final Function updateProfile;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double containerHight = 8.0;

    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            title: Text("Info"),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                title: Text("Profil bearbeiten"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => EditProfile(
            updateProfile: updateProfile),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class EditProfile extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function updateProfile;

  EditProfile({this.updateProfile});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _EditProfileStae();
  }
}

class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {
  _EditProfileState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Edit Profile')),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Save"),
                onPressed: () {
                  widget.updateProfile({
                    'title': 'Title',
                    'name': 'some name',
                    'points': 69,
                    'about': "texttexttext"
                  });
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => Tabs(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

i dont know may be i have a complet wrong approach or its just a little mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like the following. I replaced some of the widgets you didn't define with just `Text`.

Note that `children` is no longer final, you need to set it in `initState`. Also note that `_infos` cannot be final if you want to use the `_updateProfile` in the way you have it currently defined.

```
class _Tabs extends State<Tabs> {
  List<Widget> _children;
  void _updateProfile(Map<String, dynamic> newMap) {
    setState(() {
      _infos = newMap;
    });
  } //here i want to update the info i receive

  Map<String, dynamic> _infos = ({
    'title': "Title",
    'name': "name",
    'points': 73,
    'about me': "texttexttexttexttext"
  });

  @override
  void initState() {
    _children = [
      MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
          primaryColorDark: Colors.cyan[700],
          primaryColorLight: Colors.cyan[200],
          accentColor: Colors.deepOrange[200],
        ),
        home: Text(''), //not important..
      ),
      Center(child: Text("2")), //some dummy page
      Text(''), // some other dummy page
      Profile(
          userInformationen: _infosTabs,
          updateProfile:
              _updateProfile), //the Profile Page plus the Error appears "Only static members can be accessed in initializers."
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
}
```